# NSIS shortcut with java parameters

Tags: java, windows, nsis, shortcut

I am building a Java app that need parameters. The thing is that i prepared a folder with everything i need inside to run my jar. i have a javafx folder and a JRE folder to make my app standalone/non-JRE-system-dependent. this the the structure of my NSIS folder:

```
root folder
 |
 |_uninstaller.exe
 |
 |_subFolder
   |
   |_JREfolder
   |  |
   |  |_JRElibs
   |
   |_JFXfolder
   |  |
   |  |_JFXlibs
   |
   |_OtherResourcesFolders
   |_MainClass.jar 
   |_otherJars.jar
```

the thing is to launch my jar in my computer, i need to use the following sentence on a cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\java.exe" --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx13\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web,javafx.base --add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED -jar clienteCorreoDefinitivo.jar
```

so, when i made the NSIS shortcut, i tried the following sentence, but it doesnt work:

```
createShortCut "$DESKTOP\ClienteCorreoStephane.lnk" "$INSTDIR\files\java-runtime\bin\java.exe --module-path $INSTDIR\files\javafx13\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web,javafx.base --add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED -jar $INSTDIR\files\clienteCorreoDefinitivo.jar" "" "$INSTDIR\files\recursos\myicon.ico"
```

Any suggestion or help on how to launch this jar with those parameters would be awsome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
CreateShortCut \
  `$DESKTOP\ClienteCorreoStephane.lnk` \
  `$INSTDIR\files\java-runtime\bin\java.exe` \
  `--module-path "$INSTDIR\files\javafx13\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web,javafx.base --add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED -jar "$INSTDIR\files\clienteCorreoDefinitivo.jar"` \
  `$INSTDIR\files\recursos\myicon.ico`
```

(It is not *necessary* to split it to multiple lines using `\` but increases readability.)

**Explanation:**

The [syntax for `CreateShortCut`](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/CreateShortCut) is `CreateShortCut link.lnk target.file parameters icon.file` (there are more parameters, but these are the ones you need)

Now, the target file is just Java itself, so that one is set to `$INSTDIR\files\java-runtime\bin\java.exe`. The rest of the string are actually the parameters passed to Java, so they go into the 3rd parameter.

Note that I also modified the quotes a bit:

This is because your `$INSTDIR` may very well be `C:\Program Files` which contains a space. In this case, it would break because it would become `--module-path C:\Program Files\thing\files\javafx13\lib ...` and Java would read `C:\Program` as value for the module path! For this reason there have to be `"`doublequotes`"` around those paths.

However, this would clash with the quotes originally used for the whole "parameters" argument to NSIS, which is why I encapsulated that one in `` ` ``backticks`` ` `` instead of `"`doublequotes`"`. (For consistency, I used backticks for all the NSIS arguments then.)

Comment: wow! thank you very much. i worked perfectly and i also learn how to split lines.